# Disable Cufon in IE9 print / print preview

Tags: printing, styles, internet-explorer-9, cufon

I'm using Cufon as an image replacement tool. I would like to revert back to my standard font for clarity when printing.

This happens in all browsers except IE9. IE9 tries to render the fonts in Cufon.

Can anybody help me figure out a way to stop IE9 from rendering Cufon fonts in print?

Thanks, Tom.

Answer (score 3):

There is a known issue with Cufon and IE9 when printing. It has something to do with the normal styles still applying when you are printing. Best way to get around it is add in a print stylesheet and override the current styles.

Also, Add this to your print stylesheet

`cufon.cufon canvas {display:inline !important;}`